# How to change the background color of a kivy Graph?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Does it exist a property similar to the one below to change the background color of a Graph in Kivy?

test.kv

```
Graph:
    id: my_graph_id
    border_color = (0,0,0,0) # this is valid
    background_color = (0,0,0,0) # ?? this does not exist
```

Comment: In the kv file, replace `=` with `:` e.g. `background_color: (0, 0, 1, 1)     # blue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `graph.background_color` in Python code. The attribute *background_color* do exist for Kivy Garden Graph as shown below.

## Example

### main.py

```
from math import sin
from kivy.garden.graph import Graph, MeshLinePlot
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        graph = Graph(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', x_ticks_minor=5, x_ticks_major=25, y_ticks_major=1,
                      y_grid_label=True, x_grid_label=True, padding=5,
                      x_grid=True, y_grid=True, xmin=-0, xmax=100, ymin=-1, ymax=1)

        graph.background_color = 0, 0, 1, 1    # blue color

        plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
        plot.points = [(x, sin(x / 10.)) for x in range(0, 101)]
        graph.add_plot(plot)
        self.add_widget(graph)


class GraphDemo(App):
    title = "Kivy Garden Graph - background_color"

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    GraphDemo().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Kivy Garden Graph background_color is blue]